# Job parameters are not injected and skiplistener is not working in spring batch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

First problem is when I'm printing Job parameter "errorPathFile" value, it is null.

```java
@Component
@Scope(value = "step")
public class EmployeeFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<Employee> {

    @Value("#{jobParameters['errorFilePath']}")
    private String filePath;  //="C:\\Users\\prajjwal\\Documents\\errorReports.csv";

    @Override
    public Employee mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
        final Employee employee = new Employee();

        employee.setEmployeeId(fieldSet.readLong("employeeId"));

        employee.setEmployeeName(fieldSet.readString("employeeName"));
        employee.setAge(fieldSet.readInt("age"));
        employee.setPincode(fieldSet.readInt("pincode"));

        if(fieldSet.readInt("age")==4) {
            try {
                System.out.println("errorFilePath"+filePath);
            FileWriter skipReport= new FileWriter(filePath, true);
            skipReport.append("fromRead,age is 4");
            skipReport.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
            throw new MyException("age is incorrect"+fieldSet.readString("age"));

        }
        return employee;
    }

}
```

Here is how I'm injecting value:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EmployeeResource {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Value("${errorFilePath}")
    private String errorFilePath;

    @Autowired
    Job job;

    @Autowired
    JobLauncher joblauncher;

    @GetMapping("/batch")
    public ResponseEntity<?> luanch(@RequestParam("file-path") String filePath)
            throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException,
            JobParametersInvalidException {

        return ResponseEntity.ok(joblauncher.run(job, new JobParametersBuilder().addDate("date", new Date())
                .addString("filePath", filePath).addString("errorFilePath", errorFilePath).toJobParameters()).getStatus());
    }
}
```

Second problem is that `SkipListener` is not called on an skip:

```java
@Component
@StepScope
public class MySkipListener implements SkipListener<Employee, Employee> {

    @Value("#{jobParameters['errorFilePath']}")
    private String filePath;//="abc";

    @Override
    //@OnSkipInRead
    public void onSkipInRead(Throwable t) {
        if(t instanceof MyException) {
            MyException m= (MyException) t;
            try {
                System.out.println("called");
                FileWriter skipReport= new FileWriter(filePath, true);
                skipReport.append("fromRead,"+m.getMessage());
                skipReport.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new MyException("IOException occured");
            }
            }
    }

    @Override
    //@OnSkipInWrite
    public void onSkipInWrite(Employee item, Throwable t) {

        if(t instanceof MyException) {
            MyException m= (MyException) t;
            try {
                System.out.println("called");
                FileWriter skipReport= new FileWriter(filePath, true);
                skipReport.append("fromWrite,"+m.getMessage());
                skipReport.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new MyException("IOException occured");
            }
            }

    }

    @Override
    //@OnSkipInProcess
    public void onSkipInProcess(Employee item, Throwable t) {
System.out.println("innnn");
        if(t instanceof MyException) {
            MyException m= (MyException) t;
            try {
                System.out.println("called");
                FileWriter skipReport= new FileWriter(filePath, true);
                skipReport.append("fromProcess,"+m.getMessage());
                skipReport.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new MyException("IOException occured");
            }
            }
    }


}
```

Here is the configuration file:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<Employee> reader(@Value ("#{jobParameters[filePath]}") String filePath) {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Employee>().name("EmployeeReader")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource(new File(filePath))).delimited()
                .names(new String[] { "employeeId", "employeeName", "age", "pincode"}).lineMapper(lineMapper())
                .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Employee>() {
                    {
                        setTargetType(Employee.class);
                    }
                }).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LineMapper<Employee> lineMapper() {

        final DefaultLineMapper<Employee> defaultLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();

        final DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();

        lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        lineTokenizer.setStrict(false);
        lineTokenizer.setNames(new String[] { "employeeId", "employeeName", "age", "pincode"});

        final EmployeeFieldSetMapper fieldSetMapper = new EmployeeFieldSetMapper();

        defaultLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        defaultLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);

        return defaultLineMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public EmployeeProcessor employeeProcessor() {

        return new EmployeeProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Employee> writer(final DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Employee>()
                .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
                .sql("INSERT INTO employee (employee_id, employee_name,age, pincode) VALUES (:employeeId, :employeeName ,:age, :pincode)")
                .dataSource(dataSource).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job importEmployeeJob(NotificationListener listener, Step step1) {

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importEmployeeJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(listener)
                .flow(step1).end().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(JdbcBatchItemWriter<Employee> writer) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Employee, Employee>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader(null)).faultTolerant().skip(MyException.class).skipLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE).skipPolicy(new FileVerificationSkipper())
                .processor(employeeProcessor()).writer(writer)
                .listener( new MySkipListener()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ErrorTracker getErrorTracker() {
        return new ErrorTracker();
    }
}
```

Please suggest what I'm doing wrong.

Update: First problem is solved as I removed `@Component` annotations where ever I'm using `@StepScop`. But second problem:

> SkipListener not getting invoked

is not solved

Answer (score 1):

Your `EmployeeFieldSetMapper` is not correctly scoped due to `@Scope(value = "step")` which is incorrect. According to the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/StepScope.html), it should be `@Scope(value="step", proxyMode=TARGET_CLASS)`, See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3651#issuecomment-587453328.

I recommend using `@StepScope` instead.

> Job parameters are not injected and skiplistener is not working in spring batch

This is because in your step definition, you are creating a new instance of the listener yourself:

```
.listener( new MySkipListener())
```

Your listener should be declared as a spring bean so that is it proxied and gets job parameters correctly injected.

Comment: I tried but nothing worked. See update in question.

Comment: You are mixing things between declaring spring beans and creating them manually. For example, you are declaring a class `@Component EmployeeFieldSetMapper ` and then creating it manually `final EmployeeFieldSetMapper fieldSetMapper = new EmployeeFieldSetMapper();` in the `@Beanc public LineMapper<Employee> lineMapper() {}` method. Please edit the question and provide a minimal complete example that reproduces the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Only one problem solved. Now getting filePath in EmployeeFieldSetMapper but MySkipListener is still not getting invoked here `.listener( new MySkipListener())` . I removed @Component from `MySkipListener` though. (And I'll remove unnecessary code from the question and make it well formed for sure)

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine - What is the correct sequences of listener - I don't see SkipListener and WritersSkipListener doesn't works hand-in-hand?